# Void column if result of rows are null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to know if it's possible to add column only if condition is true, I mean suposse we have a simple select like:

```
SELECT
      [test1]
    , [test2]
    , [test3]
      FROM [testtable]
```

Result of this is 3 columns with data

But I want to only show column `test2` if column is not null, if all results of column `test2` are null so result should be 2 columns `(test1, test3)`is it possible to achieve that? Regards

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: This is usually better handled in your presentation logic.  Technically you could write an `if / else` statement to run 2 separate queries, one with that column, and one without, but I wouldn't necessarily recommend it...

Comment: Does not seem possible, or it would be very ugly anyway. Why do you want to do that ?

Comment: Not wise as you need a strict schema to couple your presentation logic to. But if you wanted to, you could do something with two temp tables - one with three columns and one with two - and select from the desired temp table depending on a null condition.

Comment: This is definitely left aside for a dynamically created statement with another programming language.. Don't muddy up the SQL when it can be done elsewhere, much easier.

Comment: Be careful using the answer you marked as accepted. You need to change <> NULL to IS NOT NULL or it will not do what you think it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work:

```
If (Select Count(0) From testtable Where test2 is not null) > 0
    Select test1, test2, test3 From testtable
Else
    Select test1,test3 From testtable
```

Comment: As coded this will NOT work. You are comparing test2 to NULL which will **ALWAYS** result in NULL (or zero rows in this case). Then when you count it will always be 0. Change that from <> to IS NOT and this will work.

Comment: Didn't know you changed this. +1 from me.